# delete child items with parent.clear() in mvc 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm trying to delete all of the child items in a class by first loading the items from the context and then clearing.

Model:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TicketItem> TicketItems { get; set; }
    public Ticket()
    {
        TicketItems = new List<TicketItem>();
    }
}

public class TicketItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(TicketViewModel ticketViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var ticket = ticketViewModel.Ticket;
            context.Entry(ticket).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.Entry(ticket).Collection(i => i.TicketItems).Load();
            ticket.TicketItems.Clear();
            context.SaveChanges();
            AddOrUpdateItems(ticket, ticketViewModel.Items);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(ticketViewModel);
    }

private void AddOrUpdateItems(Ticket ticket, ICollection<AssignedItem> assignedItems)
    {
        foreach (var assignedItem in assignedItems)
        {
            if (assignedItem.Assigned)
            {
                var item = context.Items.Find(assignedItem.Id);
                var ticketItem = CreateTicketItem(item, ticket);
                ticket.TicketItems.Add(ticketItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried adding the following to the model builder:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    ...
        modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>()
            .HasMany(t => t.TicketItems)
            .WithRequired(i => i.Ticket)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
    ...
    }
```

When I use the edit method in the controller I'm getting this error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I know this is related to the FK constraint in the database, I just thought that by adding the `WillCascadeOnDelete()` this would resolve the issue, as the `Clear()` would remove all child entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is that when you clear a navigation property on an entity, all you are doing is removing the link between the two items (clearing the foreign key).  You are NOT removing the entity frome the context.

Please see the StackOverflow question [Entity Framework - Clear a Child Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058697/entity-framework-clear-a-child-collection)

Comment: I looked over the code in that answer, and I'm not sure where that is supposed to go... the `CollectionChangeEventHandler` is not recognized in my project

Comment: Here is what I would do if I were you.  Compare ticket.TicketItems with ticketViewModel.Items.  For any item that exists in TicketItems but not in Items, remove it from both ticket.TicketItems AND your EF DbContext.  For any item that exists in Items but not TicketItems add it to both TicketItems and your EF DbContext.