# Entity Framework - how to remove linked elements

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have the following model:

[image]

I have an object of entity vacancy (ef_entity), given from DB, which already has one linked swap element (given from DB too). I just want to remove it:

```
        if (ef_vacancy.Swaps != null)
            ef_vacancy.Swaps.Clear();
```

when I want to do SaveChanges I get an error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

so, Entity Framework try to set "null" to Swap.VacancyID table instead of remove records. But I want to remove. If I try to do the following:

```
        var swap_to_delete = (from i in _db.Swaps where i.VacancyID == ID.Value select i).FirstOrDefault();
        if (swap_to_delete != null && _db.Entry(swap_to_delete).State != EntityState.Deleted)
            _db.Swaps.Remove(swap_to_delete);
```

It sometimes works, sometimes no work! I did not understand why it works, why not.
How to do this easy action correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2058787/1154763

The text of the answer (credit to [Craig Stuntz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7714/craig-stuntz)):

Clear() removes the reference to the entity, not the entity itself.

If you intend this to be always the same operation, you could handle AssociationChanged:

```
Entity.Children.AssociationChanged += 
new CollectionChangeEventHandler(EntityChildrenChanged);
Entity.Children.Clear();            

private void EntityChildrenChanged(object sender,
    CollectionChangeEventArgs e)
{
    // Check for a related reference being removed. 
    if (e.Action == CollectionChangeAction.Remove)
    {
        Context.DeleteObject(e.Element);
    }
}
```

You can build this in to your entity using a partial class.

Comment: Also, instead of upvoting this answer, please click on the link and upvote the original answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should delete the child items in `ef_vacancy.Swaps` one by one manually. Entity Framework doesn't do that for you. It finally cannot decide what you want to do with the old child items - if you want to throw them away or if you want to keep and assign them to other parent entities. It is not possible to just remove it from the `Swaps` collection as it cannot exist by itself, because it has a non-nullable foreign key referencing `Vacancy`(`VacancyId`). You can Delete the Swaps this way:

```
foreach (var child in ef_vacancy.Swaps)
{
   db.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Deleted;
}
```