# 'Cannot insert the value NULL' error is showing when trying to empty a collection

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework. Class ChatRoom has a List of TranscriptDownloadUserInfo class. Now when I am trying empty is using .Clear(), its showing me 'Cannot insert the value NULL';

ChatRoom.cs

```
    public class ChatRoom
    {
        [Key]
        public int Key { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TranscriptDownloadUserInfo> TranscriptDownAllowedUsers { get; set; }

        public ChatRoom()
        {
            TranscriptDownAllowedUsers = new SafeCollection<TranscriptDownloadUserInfo>();
        }
    }
```

TranscriptDownloadUserInfo.cs

```
    public class TranscriptDownloadUserInfo
    {
        [Key]
        public int Key { get; set; }

        public virtual ChatUser User { get; set; }
        public int? UserKey { get; set; }

        public bool Allowed { get; set; }
    }
```

TranscriptDownloadUserInfo Mapping

```
    public TranscriptDownloadUserInfoMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Key);

        this.ToTable("TranscriptDownAllowedUsers");
        this.Property(t => t.Key).HasColumnName("Key");
        this.Property(t => t.UserKey).HasColumnName("UserKey");
        this.Property(t => t.Allowed).HasColumnName("Allowed");

        this.HasRequired(t => t.User)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.UserKey);
    }
```

Add-Migration code

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.TranscriptDownAllowedUsers",
            c => new
            {
                Key = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                UserKey = c.Int(nullable: false),
                Allowed = c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: false),
                ChatRoom_Key = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Key)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.ChatUsers", t => t.UserKey, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.ChatRooms", t => t.ChatRoom_Key)
            .Index(t => t.UserKey)
            .Index(t => t.ChatRoom_Key);
    }
```

Code that generating the error

```
room.TranscriptDownAllowedUsers.Clear();
_repository.CommitChanges();
```

Inner-Exception

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ChatRoom_Key', table
>   'Dabb.dbo.TranscriptDownAllowedUsers'; column does not allow nulls.
>   UPDATE fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

I am not sure why is this error is occurring. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - Clear a Child Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058697/entity-framework-clear-a-child-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a contradiction `nullable: false, identity: true` because you defined the key column as an identity, so EF *assumes* `null` values can be inserted to generate a new key.

In that case you should maybe make it nullable.

That said, you [must](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5668835) make your foreign key `ChatRoom_Key` nullable, since `Clear` has to remove the references.

Comment: Good point. As I dont need that key column. Let me try to delete it. Then lets see what happen.

Comment: I've also updated my answer with another issue found: foreign key must be nullable

Answer (score 0):

Your fields are not nullable.

```
            Key = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            UserKey = c.Int(nullable: false),
            Allowed = c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: false),
            ChatRoom_Key = c.Int(nullable: false),
```

You can insert defaults or somethings, but you can't insert nothing.

Comment: by doing .clear(), I want delete all TranscriptDownAllowedUsers records for that room, I dont want to set column value null. Any suggestion ?

Comment: I'm assuming all the chatroom keys would be the same for each user in that chat room?

Comment: There would be multiple chatRooms and multiple chatUsers

Comment: I think there is a `.empty`?  A quick search, maybe this will help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection?rq=1

Comment: That error is coming from database as Entity Framework instead of doing "Delete from Dabb.dbo.TranscriptDownAllowedUsers where ChatRoom_Key='111'" this query, its doing "Update Dabb.dbo.TranscriptDownAllowedUsers set ChatRoom_Key=NULL where ChatRoom_Key='111'"... how can I fix this ?